# How can I connect medical devices like omron with flutter application

Tags: flutter, sdk, medical

I want my flutter app to have the ability to be connected with the medical devices like omron and accu-chek and take the data from it via Bluetooth..
is there a Sdk or API that enables me to do that?

I have searched but I didn't find a solution yet.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: If you didn't find any flutter package then you can do code in native Android/iOS and then using the method channel you can access those functions.